# My carrierwave.rb initializer correctly configures S3, but does not set config.storage as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave (0.10.0) uploading to S3 (`gem 'fog', '~> 1.22.1'`) testing in rSpec using Rails 4.  I have Carrierwave and S3 working in every way, but when I try to set `config.storage` in my `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`, the settings are ignored.  I also have all my S3 credentials in there, and they are working, so I am not sure why some configs are being using and other ignored.

If I set my `config.storage` in my uploader:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :fog
end
```

Everything works fine and my uploades are saved to S3.  If I remove the storage statement from my uploader and put it in `carrierwave.rb:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => ENV['FOG_PROVIDER'], 
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :region                 => 'us-west-1', 
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'bucket_name'
  config.fog_public     = false 
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
end
```

The `config.storage` setting is not set as `:fog`, and my uploads are stored in the file system as if the setting was `:file`.  This prevents me from turning off the S3 uploading when I am testing in rSpec like this:

```
# For testing, upload files to local `tmp` folder.
if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?
  config.storage = :file
  config.enable_processing = false
  config.root = "#{Rails.root}/tmp"
else
  config.storage = :fog
end
```

I would really appreciate any help figuring out what is going on here!

Thanks,

- Recon